# Notification from Celery when it cannot connect to broker?

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, ubuntu-server

I have a celery setup and running fine using rabbitmq as the broker.  I also have CELERY_SEND_TASK_ERROR_EMAILS=True in my settings.  I receive emails if there is an Exception
thrown while executing the tasks which is fine.

My question is is there a way either with celery or rabbitmq, to receive an error notification  from either celery if the broker connection cannot be established or rabbitmq itself if the rabbitmq-server running dies.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right tool for this job is a [process control system like `supervisord`](http://supervisord.org/), which launches/watches processes and can trigger events when those processes die or restart. More specifically, using the plugin `superlance`, you can [send an email when a process dies](https://github.com/Supervisor/superlance/blob/master/docs/index.rst).